# Paramater Not Supplied Error when Executing Stored Procedure

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure (SQL Server 2008) using ADO through Excel 2007 VBA. When executing the stored procedure, I'm receiving the following error: `Procedure or function 'crl_GetData' expects parameter '@StartDate', which was not supplied.`

I am supplying the parameters using the `ADODB.Command` method like so:

```
Public Function fGetMI(strStart As String, strEnd As String) As ADODB.Recordset

Dim oDB As ADODB.Connection: Set oDB = New ADODB.Connection
Dim oCM As ADODB.Command: Set oCM = New ADODB.Command
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset

oDB.Open gcConn

With oCM
    .ActiveConnection = oDB
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "crl_GetData"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@StartDate", adDate, adParamInput, , strStart)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@EndDate", adDate, adParamInput, , strEnd)
    Set oRS = .Execute 'Error thrown here'
End With

If Not oRS.BOF And Not oRS.EOF Then
    Set fGetMI = oRS
End If

oRS.Close
Set oRS = Nothing
oDB.Close
Set oDB = Nothing

End Function
```

The error is received on the line `Set oRS = .Execute`.

The stored procedure requires the `@StartDate` parameter along with the `@EndDate` parameter and the stored procedure is defined like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[crl_GetData]
    @TL varchar(128) = null,
    @Unit varchar(16) = null,
    @Site varchar(16) = null,
    @OutcomeId int = null,
    @Auth varchar(128) = null,
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            [Claim Handler],
            [Team Leader],
            [Unit],
            [Site],
            [Claim Reference],
            [Outcome],
            [Authoriser],
            [Date]

        FROM
            crl_all_data

        WHERE
            [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
            AND (@TL IS NULL OR ([TL_ID] = @TL))
            AND (@Unit IS NULL OR ([Unit] = @Unit))
            AND (@Site IS NULL OR ([Site] = @Site))
            AND (@OutcomeId IS NULL OR ([OUTCOME_ID] = @OutcomeId))
            AND (@Auth IS NULL OR ([AUTH_ID] = @Auth))

        ORDER BY
            [Date] ASC

        OPTION(RECOMPILE);
    END

GO
```

Can anyone help as to why this error is being thrown as I've used this method for executing a stored procedure many times before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
oCM.NamedParameters = True
```

before assigning the parameters, otherwise they're actually being passed by position.